# Create GraalVM native image with dockers

Tags: image, docker, native, micronaut, graalvm

I'm trying to create a GraalVM native image with Dockers. I have created a Micronaut project, and successfully create a jar application and running this inside a docker; also I've created a GraalVM native image with this jar file and now is possible to run this application, but I need to run a graalvm native image inside a docker, looking for answers in forums I found that it is necessary to build the native image inside the docker, so I have tried with this Dockerfile:

```
# use graalvm image
# replace the occurences of "product" with you jar name
FROM openjdk:8u171-alpine3.7

# expose your port, 8080 fo Micronaut applicatoin
EXPOSE 8080

# copy the fat jar
COPY build/libs/*-all.jar products.jar

# create the reflection configuration file generated by Micronaut
# for other frameworks you need to construct the file yourself
ADD . build
#RUN java -cp products.jar io.micronaut.graal.reflect.GraalClassLoadingAnalyzer

# run the native image compiler, you should already know the command arguments
# if you're not running micronaut
ENV PATH=PATHTOGRAALVM/graalvm-ce-java8-20.3.0/bin:$PATH
ENV JAVA_HOME=PATHTOGRAALVM/graalvm-ce-java8-20.3.0

CMD native-image --no-server \
             --class-path products.jar \
         -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=build/reflect.json \
         -H:EnableURLProtocols=http \
         -H:IncludeResources="logback.xml|application.yml|META-INF/services/*.*" \
         -H:Name=products \
         -H:Class=products.Application \
         -H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime \
         -H:+AllowVMInspection \
         --rerun-class-initialization-at-runtime='sun.security.jca.JCAUtil$CachedSecureRandomHolder,javax.net.ssl.SSLContext' \
         --delay-class-initialization-to-runtime=io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectEncoder,io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket00FrameEncoder,io.netty.handler.ssl.util.ThreadLocalInsecureRandom

# the native command will be used to run the application
CMD ./products
```

And it doesn't throw any exception or something, so I tried to run my docker with this:

```
docker build --tag="products-with-graavm" . 
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 products-with-graavm
```

But it does nothing, my app is not running, Is something wrong with my Dockerfile or I need to add other configuration to create my native image? Thanks.

Comment: can you check if the native-image is created or not?

Comment: Hi, I've created my native image in a docker, I deleted some lines in my native image command line that throws an exception while cretating the native image. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created my native image in a docker, I deleted some lines in my native image command line that throws an exception while cretating the native image. This lines tried to find some files that aren't in that place. Also, I delete some lines that were from an old version of GraalVM. Those lines are this:

```
-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=build/reflect.json \
-H:+AllowVMInspection \
--rerun-class-initialization-at-runtime='sun.security.jca.JCAUtil$CachedSecureRandomHolder,javax.net.ssl.SSLContext' \
--delay-class-initialization-to-runtime=io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectEncoder,io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket00FrameEncoder,io.netty.handler.ssl.util.ThreadLocalInsecureRandom
```

Thanks.